# Building FFMPEG on Windows with MSYS-2.0 Mingw-64 always fails

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to build the FFMPEG library on Windows 11 to incorporate it in my project for audio processing. Here are the steps I carried out:

- Installed MSYS2
- Update MSYS2: `pacman -Syu` followed by `pacman -Su`
- Install Required Packages: `pacman -S make pkg-config gcc yasm nasm git diffutils`
- Clone FFmpeg Source Code: `git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`
- Change directory to ffmpeg: `cd ffmpeg`
- Ran the configure script: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-shared --enable-static`
- Compile FFmpeg: `make`

I instantly got an error and compilation halted so I downloaded an earlier version of ffmpeg and something similar happened. I kept trying earlier versions with the last one being version 4.1.11 and here is the list of errors I got with this version:

```
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:356: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:421: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:479: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:640: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:707: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:774: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:870: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:957: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1059: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1216: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1361: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1453: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1568: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:1728: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:2114: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:2265: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:2602: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:2720: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
/tmp/cc7SrMT5.s:2819: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
make: *** [ffbuild/common.mak:60: libavformat/adtsenc.o] Error 1
```

Why can't I get FFMPEG to work? Does anyone have a fix for this or a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/MythTV/mythtv/issues/765

Comment: This question [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426097/question-about-building-ffmpeg-closed-as-not-about-programming-or-software-devel).

Comment: Just riffing some ideas - could you compile this in WSL?

Comment: Regarding the bug linked by Hans, could you look at what version of binutils you have, and see whether you could bump that up to the latest version that includes the fix?

Comment: @halfer Found the culprit. it was indeed the latest version of binutils, version `2.41-2`. With version `2.40-1` I was able to build ffmpeg version 4.1.11.

Comment: I've run all the commands form the question, except for third one, packages installation, which I took from the official compilation guide (+git) `pacman -S make diffutils yasm mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc git`. And had no errors, but got some errors when using your packages chain. It's that or there's some drastic difference between Windows 10 and 11 for this case. And it seems `binutils` is installed with `gcc` but not with `mingw-gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't downgrade binutils, try patching in this into ffmpeg: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/effadce6c756247ea8bae32dc13bb3e6f464f0eb

Comment: Please give more details. This currently looks like a link-only answer. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)